# File names in non-latin script changing in question marks

Tags: kubuntu, kde, language-support

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. It's necessary for me to be able to save file in non-latin script, specifically in Thai (ภาษาไทย). But file names in Thai show up as a string of question marks. This is the same in the GUI (e.g. Dolphin) and the commandline.

I implemented the following fix to solve the problem that I wasn't able to use the compose key, which also effected the problem:
commented out "run_im ibus" in .xinputrc

Before that, the Thai filenames showed up as rectangle symbols with question marks in them in the GUI and as a string of three-digit numbers divided by slashes in the commandline.

The problem also exists with other non-latin filenames such as Chinese.

Many thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell us how those files were created, but it sounds as an encoding issue to me, i.e. the file names are probably encoded in something else but UTF-8.

Consider this series of commands:

```
~$ mkdir test
~$ cd test
~/test$ touch ภาษาไทย
~/test$ ls
ภาษาไทย
~/test$ LANG=C
~/test$ ls
''$'\340\270\240\340\270\262\340\270\251\340\270\262\340\271\204\340\270\227\340\270\242'
~/test$
```

Comment: Dear Gunnar, thank you for your response. Most files were either downloaded (and renamed) or scanned pdf. Anyway, following your comment I edited the /etc/default/locale and changed all values to a desired locale in UTF-8. And everything works!

thanks!